# Not able to check the check box, exception "element not visible"

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In an table which can contain more rows, user is searchable using the email id. After searching, selecting the first check box. But selenium is throwing the element not visible exception.

> //*[@id='share_user']/tbody/tr[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xm09Q.png)/td[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xm09Q.png)//label
>
> //*[@id='share_user']/tbody/tr[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xm09Q.png)/td[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xm09Q.png)//input
>
> //label[@for='checkbox_416']

last identifier is dynamic. Still getting the element not visible exception.

Table code is mentioned below

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-hover dataTable" id="share_user"
 aria-describedby="share_user_info">
 <thead>
  <tr role="row">
   <th class="small-cell sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0"
    aria-controls="share_user" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 137px;"
    aria-label="Share Profile : activate to sort column ascending">Share Profile </th>
   <th class="medium-cell sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0"
    aria-controls="share_user" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 523px;"
    aria-label="User Details: activate to sort column ascending">User Details</th>
   <th class="medium-cell sorting_asc" role="columnheader" tabindex="0"
    aria-controls="share_user" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 366px;"
    aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Access: activate to sort column descending">Access</th>
  </tr>

 </thead>

 <tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
  <tr class="odd">

   <td class="">
    <div class="checkbox check-default">

     <input name="checkUser" id="checkbox_416" value="416" class="shareCheck"
      type="checkbox">
      <label for="checkbox_416"></label>
    </div>
   </td>
   <td class=" ">
    <img src="" class="img-responsive display-inline share-image">
     <div class="display-inline">

      <p class="share-name">alexx</p>
      <p class="muted">
       <i class="fa fa-envelope" hidden="true"></i>
       <span>alexxm360@gmail.com</span>
      </p>
     </div>
   </td>

   <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="  sorting_1">

    <div class="select2-container medium-cell" id="s2id_rolelink416"
     style="float:left;">
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return false;" class="select2-choice"
      tabindex="-1">
      <span class="select2-chosen">PROFILE ADMIN</span>
      <abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>
      <span class="select2-arrow">
       <b></b>
      </span>
     </a>
     <input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" id="s2id_autogen11"
      type="text">
      <div class="select2-drop select2-display-none select2-with-searchbox">
       <div class="select2-search">
        <input autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off"
         autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input"
         type="text">
       </div>
       <ul class="select2-results">
       </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <select name="profileUsers.roleId" id="rolelink416"
     class="medium-cell select2-offscreen" style="float:left;" tabindex="-1">
     <option value="6">PROFILE ADMIN</option>
     <option value="7">PROFILE AGENT</option>
     <option value="8">PROFILE VIEWER</option>
     <option value="196">profile role</option>

    </select>

   </td>

  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

providing the screen shots as well.
[image: xpath]

[image: html]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following expression, I have verified working fine.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='share_user']/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use explicit wait with [Expected Conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html)

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement checkbox = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='share_user']/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]//input")));
checkbox.click();
```

Comment: this was the same process I was following. I'm getting the status whether the checkbox is checked or not, but I really can't understand why this is throwing element not visible, Ran this at least 30 times now.

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy If the checkbox is added by JavaScript it might take some time until it considered visible for Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int ele_size=driver.findElements(By.xpath("locator")).size();

driver.findElements(By.xpath("locator")).get(ele_size-1).click();
```

We might encounter element not visible exception if element matching the locator existed in the DOM but is not currently visible. So we have to take the size of the element in first statement then in next statement we have to take the first element from the list and click on element.

Answer (score 0):

Used this `//*[@id='share_user']/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div` worked