# How to click on a particular checkbox

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I want to click on "Select page" checkbox which is in "All" drop down option.

html:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li>
        <input id="selectAllTop" name="selectAllCheckBox" attr-sel="All" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input type="hidden" name="_selectAllCheckBox" value="on" />
        <label for="selectAllTop" class="checkbox-label" title="Select all results">Select all</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input id="selectPageTop" name="selectPageCheckBox" attr-sel="Page" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input type="hidden" name="_selectPageCheckBox" value="on" />
        <label for="selectPageTop" class="checkbox-label" title="Select page results">Select page</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am getting this error:

```
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

I have successfully selected "All" button but having problem in checkbox, this is the code which I did but its not working.

```
button=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='selectAllOrPage']//button[@type='button']")
button.click()

time.sleep(5)
checkboxes = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='selectPageTop' and @type='checkbox']")
checkboxes.click()
```

Any type of help will be appreciable.

Thank you

Comment: 1. Target page requires authentication, so there is no need to provide the URL. Share HTML sample code instead. 2. `time.sleep(500)` SERIOUSLY?! It's **500** seconds!

Comment: I have given the HTML sample code now. @Andersson

Comment: Check this out and see if it works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41357251/not-able-to-check-the-check-box-exception-element-not-visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared the `<input>` tag have a sibling `<label>` tag. So to click on the checkbox **Select page** you can use the following line of code :

- **css_selector** :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul.list-unstyled li label[for=selectPageTop]").click()
  ```
- **xpath** :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='list-unstyled']//li//label[@for='selectPageTop']").click()
  ```

Comment: Thank you sir that CSS_selector one worked. @DebanjanB